# where the copy of variable is stored while making call by value in c++

Tags: c++

I want to know that when we *call a function by value* it makes a copy of the variable , but where in memory this copy of variable is stored

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Not necessarily, and not all processors have stacks, and it's not defined if it is the copy or the original value that is passed.

Comment: @KenY-N You're right, but for modern non-esoteric computers and systems, arguments and local variables are normally on the stack. Unless the underlying CPU have lots of registers, then the compiler may choose to put one or more arguments in registers as an optimization.

Comment: @KenY-N C++ requires some sort of stack, and you can implement a stack on any machine which is Turing complete.  And in order to support recursion, arguments must end up on the stack at some point (although I do remember an implementation of Pascal which only copied them to the stack when the function actually did recurse).

Comment: And of course, on most modern processors, the first few arguments will be passed in registers (if they fit), and only pushed onto the stack when the function calls another function.

Answer (score 5):

It's on the stack typically, before the pointer for the function call or the stack frame of the function.  I don't know if this is required by the standard, but it's probably universally done.

So take this example:

```
int f(myClass byVal)
{
    int b;
    ...
};

...

myClass myInst;
int val = f(myInst)
```

I'd expect the stack to look like at the point of the ellipsis inside of f:

```
<top> b (stack frame inside of f)
pointer to f
temp copy of myInst
myInst (stack frame of outer function).
...
```

When f returns, the stack is cleaned up to the frame of the enclosing function.

It's worth noting jogojapan's comment that optimization can cause changes, including putting some data in the machines internal registers.  You'd never want to count on internal details like this, but it's good to understand the mechanisms in common use.

Comment: To answer the implicit question: The Standard doesn't mention the stack or the role it plays. The Standard just says these variables are local (automatic) variables. (Also, whether they are _really_ on the stack, depends on optimization of course. They may as well be in a register, for example.)

Comment: @jogojapan: Thanks, I knew someone would come to the rescue on that point!

Comment: @jogojapan Conceptually, they are on a stack.  Practically, I think 32 bit Intel is about the only platform which doesn't pass the first few in registers (but it must push the registers onto the stack before calling any other functions).

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, but there is not only the question of whether they are _passed_ in registers. Even ordinary local variables may exist only in registers, e.g. because they are used only for a few instructions and need not have an address. But yes, conceptually they are on a stack because they exist only for the duration of the current function call. But if "stack" refers to a portion (or indeed a segment) of memory, then they need not be located there.

Comment: @JamesKanze Then again, coming to think of it, if they are not _passed_ in registers (but pushed onto the stack), they will have a place on the stack for the rest of that function call, so you are right. It's a matter of whether they are passed through registers (which is very common, as you said).

Comment: @jogojapan With regards to other local variables: the standard makes no requirements there either.  The "protocol" for both arguments and local variables is a stack, so you can say that they are "on the stack".  Even if the hardware doesn't have a stack, or the system doesn't recognize a stack segment.  (In most multithreaded environments, the different threads will have "stacks" allocated on the heap: a hardware stack, because it will be addressed using `ESP`, but in the "heap" segment.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes; I don't think there is any disagreement between what you say and what I say. Just to be clear: I did not initially refer to the "conceptual" stack, simply because the Standard does not define it (even if it implies it somehow). When I say "stack" (as opposed to "heap"), I mean a memory area dedicated to hold local variables and other data specific to individual instances of function calls. Whether a piece of data is located in that area (regardless of how it relates to memory segmentation) is significant for a number of reasons, not least because it tends to be in L1 cache. It

Comment: (cont'd) ...was my assumption that this is what the questioner referred to. (Obviously, I tend to think it terms of common, modern architectures, esp. x86 and x86_64, and the hardware (such as caches) they usually come with.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Codie CodeMonkey said, on most current computers, the copy will be on the stack. However, there are notable exceptions:

On platforms with a decent amount of registers (the old PowerPC and the entire Power series are an example, another one is the Sparc, I would define "decent amount" to mean at least 32 registers), the copies are actually made from one register to another register. On these platforms, there are strict rules, which registers a function may change and which not. Local variables are typically held in the registers which may not be changed by any called functions, so no memory access is necessary for them. Only, when the called function decides that it needs to use some of the registers it must not change, will it save the contents of those registers onto the stack before it overwrites them.

So the typical life of a value on such platforms is this:

- Function a writes it into a register (r31) that may not be changed by function calls.
- Function a copies the value into a register that is used for register passing (r3). Both copies reside in registers.
- Function a calls function b.
- Function b needs to call function c, after which call it still needs the value. So it takes a number of registers and saves them on the stack (including register r31 that originally held our value). Now there are three copies of the value: two in registers and one on the stack.
- Function b copies the value into its old register (r3 -> r31), not knowing that it was there already. It calls function c. After this call, there is still one saved copy on the stack and one in register r31.
- Function b does whatever it needs to do with our value. Finally, it restores the registers which it was not supposed to modify by loading their old value from the stack. From Function b's perspective, this destroys its working copy of the value in register r31, however, we still have one copy of the value in a register and one on the stack.
- Function b returns, destroying its stack allocation, the stack copy of the value fades into oblivience. Only the original copy of the value within function a remains where it should be: in register r31.

Even though this approach seems complicated, it entails significantly fewer stack memory accesses than the X86-approach. Especially leaf routines that do not need to call any other functions, do not need to access the stack at all.